# DNS reverse name look up

Tags: java, networking, dns, ip

I am new to Java network programming.
Here is the code:

```
InetAddress add=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
byte[] arr=add.getAddress();
System.out.println(InetAddress.getByAddress(arr).getHostName());
```

Expected Output:  www.google.com
Found output:     sa-in-f147.1e100.net

After little survey on web, I found that after 2009 google started using name of domain as 1e100.net to conflate separate domains for youtube, google and other google products.

Still I cannot understand what is happening here and how local dns server chooses one entry over other for multiple mapping for same ip address.

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en

Comment: This isn't really a programming issue; it has to do with how the [DNS system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) works.  It's not your _local_ DNS server that's making the decision on what to return.